# Create an XML page by a custom module

Tags: hooks

I need to create an XML page. I created a page with my custom module, and I tried to display it, but it showed as a normal Drupal page with blocks.

```
function my_custom_function_name_xml_list() {
  $output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">';

  return $output;
}
```

How do I avoid Drupal adds its own content to the output of my function?

Comment: Have you completed this task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of returning the string you want to use as output, print it using code similar to the following one.

```
print $output;
module_invoke_all('exit');
exit();
```

`$output` is the variable containing the output you want to show.
While the `module_invoke_all('exit')` call is not strictly necessary, it notifies other modules that Drupal is terminating. There are modules that implement [hook_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_exit/6) to do their job, and they will not work, without that call; their purpose is to write something in a Drupal variable, or in a database table, and they don't interfere with the output your are producing.

The reason why it is necessary to do this is the code used by [index.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/6), which contains the following:

```
$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
      drupal_site_offline();
      break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
  print theme('page', $return);
}

drupal_page_footer();
```

If you return a string, it is passed to `theme('page')`, which renders the page as you are noticing; if you return nothing, then both `is_int($return)` and `isset($return)` are `FALSE`, and the relative code is not executed.

The equivalent for Drupal 7 for the code I wrote for Drupal 6 would be the following one:

```
print $output;
drupal_exit();
```

[drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7) contains already the call to `module_invoke_all('exit')`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all you need is [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) and [`node_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_feed/7.x) to create a basic RSS feed matching the [RSS 2.0 Specification](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).

`node_feed()` then ensures by calling `drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8')` the correct headers getting applied and only RSS markup getting rendered.

#### But if you want a really, really custom XML feed ...

... you have to write your own `node_feed()` function and further on your own [`format_rss_channel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_channel/7.x) and [`format_rss_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_item/7.x) functions. I simply pasted these three functions into a custom module, renamed them, and customized them for my own needs. Here's a simplified example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {

  $items = [];

  $items['custom.xml'] = [
    'page callback'   => '_custom_feed_page_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ];

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Return feed for indicated content.
 */
function _custom_feed_page_callback() {

  $nids = db_select('node', 'n');
  $nids->fields('n', ['nid', 'created']);
  $nids->condition('n.status', 1);
  $nids->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC');
  $nids->range(0, 10);
  $nids = $nids->execute()->fetchCol();

  _custom_xml_node_feed($nids);
}

/**
 * Generates and prints a custom XML feed.
 */
function _custom_xml_node_feed($nids) {

  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  $items = '';
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    $node->link = url("node/$node->nid", ['absolute' => TRUE]);

    $items .= _custom_xml_format_rss_item($node->title, $node->link);
  }

  global $base_url;

  $channel_defaults = array(
    'title' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'),
    'link' => $base_url,
  );

  $output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>\n";
  $output .= "<!DOCTYPE CUSTOM.EVENTS SYSTEM \"custom_import.dtd\">\n";
  $output .= "<CUSTOM.EVENTS version=\"2.25\">\n";
  $output .= _custom_xml_format_rss_channel($channel_defaults['title'], $channel_defaults['link'], $items);

  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');
  print $output;
}

/**
 * Formats an XML channel.
 */
function _custom_xml_format_rss_channel($title, $link, $items) {

  $output = "  <EVENTLIST>\n";
  $output .= "    <SOURCE id=\"12345\">\n";
  $output .= '      <TITLE>' . check_plain($title) . "</TITLE>\n";
  $output .= '      <LINK>' . check_url($link) . "</LINK>\n";
  $output .= "    </SOURCE>\n\n";

  $output .= $items;
  $output .= "  </EVENTLIST>\n";
  $output .= "</CUSTOM.EVENTS>\n";

  return $output;
}

/**
 * Formats a single XML item.
 */
function _custom_xml_format_rss_item($title, $link) {

  $output = "    <EVENT>\n";
  $output .= '      <TITLE>' . check_plain($title) . "</TITLE>\n";
  $output .= '      <LINK>' . check_url($link) . "</LINK>\n";
  $output .= "    </EVENT>\n\n";

  return $output;
}
```

---

Credits: I got the idea to do it that way after reading this brilliant blog post https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/creating-rss-feeds-with-a-light-hand

Parked working example module on GitHub https://github.com/leymannx/custom_feed

Comment: How would I do it with Drupal 9 when I dont want to output RSS but just plain XML (to send it to another api)?

Comment: @user6329530 – With a custom controller.